# Angular 11 and preserving a base url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I recently added another project to our platform and it is using the latest and greatest angular. However, in older versions I was able to support something like this:

example.com/booking-widget  which would return an angular app and change the URL to this: example.com/booking-widget#/landing.  It would simply append the routing to the end of the url that got it there.

With angular 11 I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this. It converts example.com/booking-widget to example.com/#/landing once the router kicks in.  We have many projects where the URL to the server is the resource for that particular angular app.

Anyone know if it is still possible to preserve it?
I have looked into base-href which yielded example.com/#/booking-widget/landing and been playing around with some of the ExtraOptions for the router but with no luck.
Thank you!

Comment: in base href was /booking-widget

Comment: is booking-widget a root of your app or a part of inapp routing ?

Comment: it is in the root of the app. The server side picks up that route and returns the index.html page for that particular feature

Comment: I don't really understand why is /#/ a problem? This is how it was supposed to work and the booking-widget#/landing is wrong.

Comment: the booking-widget is a server side resource that returns the html page. I want that part of the url to be preserved. Once the page loads the angular app can take over using hash routing to deal with its sub routes.  The problem is I need to still have the original resource url booking-widget before the hash so on page reload it can find the appropriate SPA